# how they make today's google doodles

Tags: javascript, html, css

i saw today's logo of google and i am impressed. i want to know how they make it. i think a lot of Jquery and AJAX used. Anybody know??

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you could link to `today's` doodle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have an image overlaid with transparencies (the stylised Google logo).

They are animating the `rotate` CSS property.

Firebug (or equivalent web inspector tool) is your friend.

Comment: i see it in firebug the logo is a .png but i want to know how they rotate it.

Comment: @enthusiastic They are animating the CSS `rotate` property with JavaScript.